# Modify method logic MOQ

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to unit testing so my questions might seem basic, apologies for that.

I am trying to figure out if there is such API in MOQ that can help me to modify a method logic.
I mean,
When calling . I want to increase lets say my "count" variable by 1 and then call the method or do something else, doesn't really matter.

There is no code yet, this is a principle question. Could not find it in the MOQ Documentation on GitHub.

Hope I was clear and you can help me with that.

Thank you!

Comment: You want to use Moq to change the code you're testing? That doesn't sound right. What are you actually trying to test?

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstrates your issue. See also [mcve].

Comment: You don't modify the _logic_ of the method your testing. You modify the inputs or ambient data and assert the method behaves the way it should. If you modify the logic instead of the data all your testing is the modified logic not the actual method under test.

Comment: I am not a developer, but I am supposed to provide this info. For example, after looking at Typemock's documentation I found this:

Comment: http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmodifyingmethodlogic.htm As you can see, "DoInstead" does what I am trying to explain

Comment: How about [Moq Callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#CallBacks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't 'modify' the method logic per se, but you can replace it entirely.

When you create a mock of an interface, you aren't instantiating a specific concrete type of that interface. Instead, you are allowing your mocking framework to create a 'mock' version of that interface; an object which, by default, has no functionality but requires no work to instantiate.

The easiest way to do this is to use Moq's Setup functionality, which is explained well here:

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart